# What is the difference between "call" and "callonce" in karate API?

Tags: json, karate

Could anyone please explain the actual difference between call and callonce in karate testing API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#callonce

I'll quote below:

> Karate's callonce keyword behaves exactly like call but is guaranteed to execute only once. The results of the first call are cached, and any future calls will simply return the cached result instead of executing the JavaScript function (or feature) again and again.

Comment: Hi Peter, looking for some clarification :) Does `callonce` only cache the result for the duration of a `Feature` or will the cashed result persist across multiple `Feature`s (or is that what callSingle does?)

Comment: @OwenKuhn yes `callonce` is only for the feature, and if you need to init something across the whole suite run, use `karate.callSingle()`